# How does exactly maven creates effective plugin configuration for the same execution ids?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have the following plugin configuration in my project:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>AA</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>the_same_id</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and the following plugin configuration in my parent pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lineEnding>LF</lineEnding>
                <includes>
                    <include>A</include>
                    <include>B</include>
                    <include>C</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>the_same_id</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sort</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run *mvn help:effecive:pom* this is the merged configuration of my plugin:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.revelc.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>the_same_id</id>
        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
          <goal>sort</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>AA</include>
          </includes>
          <lineEnding>LF</lineEnding>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>AA</include>
      </includes>
      <lineEnding>LF</lineEnding>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

According to [this](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) the default merging behavior of the plugins configuration:

> is to merge the content of the configuration element according to element name.

which is shown in the *includes* section as it only contains the ones from the project pom and not from the parent pom. However following that logic I don't understand why the effective-pom configuration contains two goals rather than only the one from the project configuration.

Comment: You can control how configuration is taken. First you have a difference between a global configuration in a plugin (outside the execution block) as given in your first example. If you like to have this configuration to be additive you have to define `<includes combine.children="append">` which will add the entries to one defines in it's parent. Please read in detail https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugins

Comment: In this particular case I was rather trying to learn why maven behaves as it is instead of controlling it by using `combine` options. The main problem is the merging behavior for lists is different between `includes` and `goals`. I would expect both of the them giving the same results meaning that `goals` should only contain the `check` goal.

Comment: Goals are something different than a configuration parameter... The difference is between configuration blocks (or more accurate the information within the configuration) and goal block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: It **is** properly documented in [POM reference, plugins section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugins). Thanks [Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise)  for pointing this out!

In [the codebase responsible for merging](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/merge/MavenModelMerger.java#L591) it is slightly different for each of the properties.

If your goals are not excluded, then [these will be merged together](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-model-builder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/merge/MavenModelMerger.java#L603).

Also, your configuration may be merged differently, given [the plugin's lifecycle configuration](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/76d7f58a61eb6aea8d2e8b78551e5d500cc74f6e/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/model/plugin/DefaultLifecycleBindingsInjector.java#L168) too.

Comment: You should take a deep look at: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#plugins